# What is my registered address for UK car insurance?

Tags: united-kingdom, car-insurance, covid-19, working-at-home

I am about to buy a car and I need to put down my registered address for both the car insurance and VC5 logbook etc.

I own a house in City X, and this is where I work and vote etc. However, due to covid, I have been working from home and living in City Y (relative's address) for approximately 1 year. I only go to City X very infrequently just to check the post etc. This will continue until covid is over / WHF ends.

Which city/address should I put down?

1. Is it my "actual home" that I own and registered to vote at? (Address X)
2. Is it where the car is likely to be physically parked and driven the majority of time (Address Y)?
3. Or does it matter? Would either be ok given I can be contacted at both?

Note:

- I do not care about saving money on finding cheaper insurance. **I care about doing the right thing legally**.
- If this is the wrong stack exchange site to ask this question, please could you recommend an alternative?

Answer (score 9):

I'm pretty sure that any time I've applied for car insurance I've had to specify both the registered address (for you, Address X) and the address where the car is normally kept (for you, Address Y) with no assumption that these are necessarily the same.

Are you filling in details through a comparison site or directly with an insurer? If the latter then I would ask them directly if the form doesn't provide this option.

Answer (score 0):

@Vicky is right to say you should give both if possible.

The insurance company wants to know where the car spends most of it's time as that's what drives the premium so if you can only give one address that's the one you give them.

The Government wants to know where to find you if there is an issue (speeding ticket etc) so again if you can only give one answer that's it.

Comment: The *government* is not very interested in your motoring habits, but the *police* most certainly are. The log book address should be somewhere that you can be easily contacted at any time, not somewhere you only visit once a year. In some circumstances the police may attempt to contact you by knocking on the door, not by sending you snail-mail, and annoying them by being "hard to find" is *not* a good strategy - the more time they have to spend on an inquiry, the greater their incentive to find *some* offence to charge you with, to get some "return on their investment!".

Comment: ... as a personal example of a genuinely innocent person (myself) suddenly becoming of interest to the police, I once got a "knock on the door" in the UK when a car that I had sold privately was involved in a serious accident, two days after I had sold it - I had submitted the change of ownership data to the DVLA as required by law, but the DVLA database had not yet been updated.